# I get error 1146 when I try to access some tables on my live database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1146

Two tables on my database are visible on the sidebar but produce the error message ‘#1146- Table ‘prefix_dbname.tablename’ does not exist’ when I try to open it. The pages on my website that display data from the table are empty as well but all the other tables are still there and the pages displaying from them are fine.
Please, is there any way I can restore or fix this problem? I’m as good as dead if this doesn’t get resolved. Most of the posts I’ve seen addressing this problem are dealing with databases on the localhost but this one is live.
Please help.

Comment: The table doesn't exist, we didn't delete it so we can't tell why it's not there anymore

Comment: Sorry but sometimes it’s good to have a backup of a live database...

Comment: @Alon Eitan I didn’t think you did. I’m just in a really bad spot and asking for help. Do you know if there’s any way I can restore the deleted table?

Comment: @claus Bönnhoff thank you. I’ve learnt that now. Can I possibly restore the deleted tables?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think that you can if you don't have a backup, did you check it with your hosting provider?

Comment: @alon Eitan thank you for your help. I’m doing that now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by contacting my hosting provider and asking for a backup.